# Dynamically create an Envelope with pre-defined DocuSign templates

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

We are trying to create a solution that would allow us to dynamically create an envelope using pre-defined DocuSign templates. Meaning that the templates will be pre-built, but depending on certain field values in Salesforce, we could programmatically (dynamically) create an envelope so that:

- In one scenario, an envelope will be created with documents A and B
- In another scenario, an envelope will be created with documents A, B, and C
- In a third scenario, an envelope will be created with only document C

Our requirement being that the selection and creation of this envelope is not manually done by the user, but programmatically and dependent on Salesforce field values from a custom object.

We're beginning to explore the newly released Apex Toolkit, and we'd greatly appreciate a point in the right direction & some insight from the devs behind the Docusign for Salesforce - Core package.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the potent use cases for us  building the Apex toolkit. The scenario outlined above can be definitely achieved via the pre-built envelope creation methods exposed as a part of the Apex toolkit. Please go through the sample code provided in this link below.
https://developers.docusign.com/salesforce/code-examples/salesforce-sending-signing-template
Ideally you should be able to invoke this and tie it to any custom logic that references Apex in your Salesforce instance. Do let us know if you have any specific question regarding the same and we will assist you.

Sample example:
Account Stage set to XYZ
Trigger on Account for after update
Incorporates a future method with callout=true and this future method will call the Apex toolkit methods for creating envelopes